# Что означает собака в комментариях java script ?

Tags: javascript

Один из комментариев в koa.js.

```
 /**
   * Shorthand for:
   *
   *    http.createServer(app.callback()).listen(...)
   *
   * @param {Mixed} ...
   * @return {Server}
   * @api public
   */
```

Особенно не понимаю почему это выделяется особым синтаксисом.

https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/application.js#L56

Comment: Это для документации

Comment: jsdoc . . . . .

Answer (score 3):

Это делается для отображения переменных, которые можно использовать в функции ниже. В данном случае это функция `listen(...args) {}`, где `...args` и есть параметры, то есть переменные для ввода. Делается это так же для того, чтобы в современных редакторах появлялись подсказки при вызове функции. Это бывает удобно, когда много функции и не нужно залезать в место её объявления, чтобы посмотреть её же параметры.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!